# How to retrieve the current querystring values using mootools

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

How to retrieve the current querystring values using mootools.

I am using mootools ajax for php pagination. Following parameters are passing with my first call

```
format=html&nolayout=true&p[0]=1000-1500&p[1]=1500-2000&p[2]=2000-2500
```

and for the second ajax call should retain the above all parameters and need to attach one more parameter as follows

```
format=html&nolayout=true&p[0]=1000-1500&p[1]=1500-2000&p[2]=2000-2500&pagenum=1
```

How to do this.any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location) i.e.

Get the current QS and remove the first character `?`, and also `&pagenum=X` ([replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) + [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp)), then append the new param and send your ajax request.

```
var currQueryString = window.location.search.substring(1), //and also remove '&pagenum=X' (see above)
    newQueryString = currQueryString + "&pagenum=1"; //obv, pagenum should be dynamic, this is just an example

new Request({ //or Request.HTML...
  url : 'http://some/url' // ...and other options
}).send(newQueryString);
```